# I need help understanding what a line in a JavaScript algorithm does

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Im working on breaking down an algorithm called Top K Frequent Elements below i have the link to the problem and the solution. I cant understand what the 4th line is doing specifically on the right side of the = sign, could someone explain to me what it is that im assigning to the map[elements], it seems to perhaps be short hand for some type of if conditional because of the || statement but that is my best guess. If im missing any information or if my question is not clear please let me know and I will update the question as soon as I can
https://leetcode.com/problems/top-k-frequent-elements/description/

```
var topKFrequent = (nums, k) => {
let map = {}
for(let element of nums){
    map[element] = (map[element] || 0) + 1
}
return Object.entries(map).sort((a,b) => b[1] -a[1]).map(val=>Number(val[0])).slice(0,k);
}
```

Comment: `map[element] || 0` is just `map[element]`, or, if thats is falsy (as in `null`, `undefined`,`0`, `false`, `''`) it will be `0`. So basically this is just `0` as default if `map[element]` is not a number I assume. Then it is incremented by 1.

Comment: If `map[element]` has not been initialized, it will be `undefined` and therefore "falsy".  The `||` operator will then evaluate the other side, which is 0. So it says "give me either `map[element]` or, if it's unset, 0".

Answer (score 0):

We're examining this `(map[element] || 0) + 1`

- `map[element]` looks up a specific value in the array
- `|| 0` effectively returns a default value of 0 if the lookup above fails
- `+ 1` adds one to the value from above

There is a newer and slightly cleaner way to handle this with the nullish coalescing operator [??](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing). It accomplishes the same "default value" approach but removes some of the gotchas that may happen with the or operator `||`.